# RewriteRule domain which contains '?'

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I want to have RewriteRule where domain's /page/test or /page/test/ go to www.domain.com. Only for this two example.
I try:

```
RewriteRule ^/page/test/?$ http://www.domain.com [R=301,L,NC]
```

This will be good but I have other pages like /page/test/?D_test
and when I put RewriteRule, redirect also /page/test/?D_test. Problem is '?'. How should I write my rule to don't rewrite another page's to www.domain.com ? for example

```
/page/test/?D_test /page/test/(.*)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question. You are either asking how can I redirect all the traffic including the query string to the domain and take off the query string. In that case I usually do it this way:

```
RewriteRule ^/page/test/?$ http://www.domain.com? [R=301,L,NC]
```

If you want to make it so it doesn't redirect if there is a query string then you have to use a rewrite conditional.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^/page/test/?$ http://www.domain.com? [R=301,L,NC]
```